# How to relay http web request to on premise api based on web sockets

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-servicebusrelay, self-host-webapi, system.net.websockets

I have to implement an arquitecture for sorting out the problem represented by the following picture:

[Cloud to On-Premise API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apBo7.png)

Basically, I have to deploy a public API in the cloud (Azure), but the data are located in on-premise machines. The on-premise machines expose a Swagger API that provides the data. Each on-premise machine has a unique identifier (installation identifier) that allow us to route the requests.

I have developed a solution based on the Relay module of Azure Service Bus following the approach suggested in the following link:

[Secure Internet Access to an On-Premise API](http://work.haufegroup.io/secure-internet-access-to-onpremise-api/)

The solution based on the Relay module of Azure Service Bus sort out my problem and fits most of my needs, but it has one problem, the latency is awful.

I have deployed the public API and the service bus endpoint in the same geographic region and a simple request GET /companies takes 1.5 seconds on average, the processing time in the on-premise API is very low, just a couple of miliseconds ..

In order to keep the latency low, I have been thinking in using web sockets, but I don't know if is the best approach bearing in mind the scenario because for each request to the public API i would have to open a web socket channel to the on-premise API inside the ApiController and take care of the lifecycle of it (close it before give back the response).

Obviously, in this scenario, each ApiController in the on-premise API should provide support for web sockets and http at the same time.

Another solution, it would be to implement a http proxy that relay the original request from the public API to the on-premise API but, from my point of view, the best latency possible is achieved using a communication P2P without connectivity managers in the middle, for that reason my focus is now on web sockets.

I want to meet the standards as much as possible, for this reason I want to use "pure" web sockets, this means not use Signalr.

Once, I have exposed my problem, the solution and the alternatives, my questions are as follows:

1. How can I open a web socket inside an action method of a ApiController class and relay the original http request from the public API to the on-premise API?
2. How can I provide support in the on-premise API for both protocols HTTP and WebSockets. The on-premise API should be able to process HTTP requests but also WebSocket requests.
3. My first bet is using System.Net.WebSockets, but I would like to know if exists any websockets library that shines when is integrated with ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 0):

> a simple request GET /companies takes 1.5 seconds on average, the processing time in the on-premise API is very low, just a couple of miliseconds

You are using Azure Relay service to securely expose services to the public cloud, as far as I know, we would not achieve the same latency as an on-premise server due to many factors affecting (for example the client has to first authenticate to the Service Bus Relay).

Besides, [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part) explained with example how to create custom HTTP handler to accept client WebSocket requests, you could refer to it to modify your API app to handle WebSocket requests.